# Solving two nonlinear equations in two unknowns

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

This is my code defining two nonlinear equations. I want to solve them simultaneously.

```
order = 1;
m = 1; 
g = 9.81; 
ks = 100 ;
omega2 = Sqrt[ks/m]; 
R = -0.7;

Hp0[k_, l_] := 2*m*g*l*k^2;
Hs0[Js_] := omega2*Js;
Jp[k_, l_] := 8*m*l^2*Sqrt[g/l]/Pi * ( EllipticE[k^2] - (1 -k^2)*EllipticK[k^2]);
q[k_] := Exp[-Pi*EllipticK[1 - k^2]/EllipticK[k^2]];
coeff[k_, Js_, n_] := 
  6*m*g*Sqrt[2*Js/m/omega2] / EllipticK[k^2]^2 * Pi^2 * n*q[k]^n/(1 - q[k]^(2*n));
phipdot[k_, Js_, n_, l_] := 
  D[Hp0[k, l], k]/D[Jp[k, l], k] + D[coeff[k, Js, n], k]/D[Jp[k, l], k];
phisdot[k_, Js_, n_] := omega2 + D[coeff[k, Js, n], Js];

(* Equation1 is 2n*phi_p_dot-phi_s_dot == 0 *)
Equation1[k_, Js_, n_, l_] := 2*n*phipdot[k, Js, n, l] - phisdot[k, Js, n];
(* Equation2 is Hamiltonian is constant *)
Equation2[k_, Js_, n_, l_] := Hp0[k, l] + Hs0[Js] + coeff[k, Js, n];
```

I want to solve for `Equation1 = 0` and `Equation2 = 0` for `n = 1` and `l = 1`.

Comment: Your title and question are not consistent about the desired value of `n`. Should it be `1` or `2`? Please edit question to clarify rather than responding with a comment.

Comment: Talking a bit about where these equations came from might be helpful in solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial investigation. I replaced your Equation1 with

```
ClearAll[Equation1];

Equation1[k_, Js_, n_, l_] := 
  Evaluate[2*n*phipdot[k, Js, n, l] - phisdot[k, Js, n]];
```

This gets the derivative done at the definition stage. Otherwise you are giving k a value and then asking it to do symbolic differentiation with a number not a variable.

I then did

```
ContourPlot[{Equation1[k, Js, 1, 1] == 0}, {k, -2, 2}, {Js, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This gives the contour along which Equation1 equals zero. We now need to find a similar contour for Equaiton2. However, I could not find values where this happened. Then I did this to look at typical values of Equation2.

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[Equation2[k, Js, 1, 1], {Js, 0, 10, 1}], {k, -2, 
  2}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 200}}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Range[0, 10, 1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This does not suggest there is a parameter range where Equation2 is zero except for the case Js =0 and k = 0.

Do you know ranges for k and Js?

Hope that helps.

Comment: range of k is from 0 to 1. range of Js we do not know.

Comment: Well it looks like Js =0 is the only solution. Have you tried to take my last plot further with a wider range for Js? Does the function go down towards zero again?